# Construct value from Kind in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I'd like to go from a type to value as follows, but without using the depreciated DatatypeContexts:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}          
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}   

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

data (KnownNat n) => MagicN n a = MagicN a             
  deriving (Show)                                      

getMagicN :: forall n. (KnownNat n) => MagicN n Integer
getMagicN = MagicN $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)         

MagicN five = getMagicN :: MagicN 5 Integer
```

I'm not too concerned if this or another method (Peano numbers etc) is used; the requirement is to be able to construct the value from the type information alone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a better way to constrain the kind of `MagicN`'s first parameter. `{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}` will give you just what you need.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

data MagicN (n :: Nat) a = MagicN a
  deriving (Show)
```

All the rest is the same.

Note: `KindSignatures` is implied by `PolyKinds` and by `TypeFamilies`, so if you're using either of the latter you won't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!